# OAuth2 Discord 'unsupported_grant_type'

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

So, I was making a website and I needed Discord's OAuth2

However, this error keeps popping up for me:

```
    data: { error: 'unsupported_grant_type' }
```

This here is my code:

```js
function getToken(code) {
    const data = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: 'ops',
        client_secret: 'ops',
        code: code,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5500/callback',
        scope: 'identify'
    })
    axios({
        url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: data.toString()
    }).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}
```

Just tried looking it up on the internet about. Since I was used to the old OAuth, I tried the old way. As I couldn't, I went after information in the Discord documentation. And I got this information.
However, without success.